# How to post a file uploaded in View from Webgrid to Controller as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a Webgrid in the form where i am getting some values from the Model.
I need to attach a File for e.g and email file. I am able to pass the filename but the file itself
i need to pass to the controller which i am unable to do.

Below is the sample code i have written:

View

```
 <div id="employeeGrid">
            @if (Model.OnboardedEmployees.Any())
            {
                @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "table",
                columns: grid.Columns(

                                grid.Column("EmployeeID", "Employee ID", format: @<text> @item.EmployeeID</text>, style: "p13"),
grid.Column("EmployeeName", "Employee Name", format: @<text> @item.EmployeeName</text>),
grid.Column("GOL.GOLName", "GOL Name", format:@<text> @item.GOL.GOLName</text>),
grid.Column("Account.AccountName", "Project Name", format:@<text> @item.Account.AccountName</text> ),
grid.Column(header: "Reason", format: (item) => @Html.DropDownList("ReasonID", Model.Reasons.Select(u => new SelectListItem
{
Text = u.Text,
Value = u.Value,
Selected = u.Value == ((WebGridRow)item)["ReasonID"].ToString()
}), new { @class = "form-control" })),
grid.Column(header: "Release Date", format: item => Html.TextBox("ReleaseDate", item.ReleaseDate as Object, new {  @type = "date", @class = "form-control ReleaseDate" })),
grid.Column(header: "Attach File", format: @<text><input type="file"  class="approvalFile" style="display:none;" /><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="attachFileBtn" value="Upload" style="color: #318dc3;"><i class="fas fa-1_5x fa-envelope"></i></a> </text>),
//grid.Column(header: "Release Date", format: item => Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ApprovalEmailFile, new { id = @item.ApprovalEmailFile, @type = "file", @class = "form-approvalFile", style = "display:none"  })),
grid.Column(header: "Off Board", format: @<text><a class="offboardBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url='@Url.Action("SaveOffboardingDetails")' data-employeeid="@item.EmployeeID"  data-accountid="@item.Account.AccountId" style="color: #318dc3;"><i class="fas fa-1_2x fa-user-times"></i></a></text>),
grid.Column(header: "Checklist", format: @<text><a class="openChecklistBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url='@Url.Action("Checklist")' data-employeeid="@item.EmployeeID" style="color: #318dc3;"><i class="fas fa-1_5x fa-clipboard-list"></i></a></text>)

)
)
            }

jquery code on click of the attachfile button

$(document).on("click", '.offboardBtn', function () {
             debugger;
             var url = $(this).data('url');
             var reasonid = $(this).parents('tr').find('#ReasonID').val();
             var filename = $(this).parents('tr').find('.approvalFile').val();
             var releasedate = $(this).parents('tr').find('.ReleaseDate').val();
             var empID = $(this).data('employeeid');
             var accID = $(this).data('accountid');
             var fileUpload = $(".approvalFile").get(0);
             var file = fileUpload.file;


             $.post(url, { reasonID: reasonid, fileName: filename, employeeID: empID, releaseDate: releasedate, accountID: accID, AttachFile: fileUpload }, function (data) {

                 $('#employeeGrid').html(data);

             });
         });
```

Controller method

```
 public ActionResult SaveOffboardingDetails(int reasonID, string fileName, int employeeID, int accountID, DateTime releaseDate, HttpPostedFileBase AttachFile)

        {
            try
            {
                OnboardedEmpVM objonboardedempVM = new OnboardedEmpVM();
                OnboardedEmployee objonboardedemp = new OnboardedEmployee();

                int result = 0;
                result = objOffboardingBLL.SaveOffboardingDetails(reasonID, employeeID, accountID, releaseDate);

                if (releaseDate == DateTime.Now && (reasonID == 2 || reasonID == 4))
                {
                    int employeeresult = 0;
                    employeeresult = objOffboardingBLL.OffBoardEmployeeDetails(employeeID);

                    int infraresult = 0;
                    infraresult = objOffboardingBLL.DeleteInfraDetails(employeeID);

                    int projectresult = 0;
                    projectresult = objOffboardingBLL.OffboardProjectDetails(employeeID, accountID);

                }
```

Model class

```
public class OnboardedEmployee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        public GOL GOL { get; set; }

        public Account Account { get; set; }

        public string CorpID { get; set; }

        public string EmailID { get; set; }

        public int ReasonID { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        public string Filename { get; set; }

       public HttpPostedFileBase Doc_File { get; set; }

     //   public string Document_Path { get; set; }
    }
```

View Model

```
public class OnboardedEmpVM
    {
        public List<OnboardedEmployee> OnboardedEmployees { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Reasons { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase ApprovalEmailFile { get; set; }
    }
```

Please let me know how i can pass the file from View to Controller so that i can save the
uploaded file

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using ajax call as below.

So closing this.

```
if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                 var fileUpload = $(this).parents('tr').find('.approvalFile').get(0);
                 var files = fileUpload.files;
                 var formData = new FormData();
                 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                     formData.append("approvalfile", files[i]);
                 }                  
             }
             else {  
                    alert("FormData is not supported.");  
             }

$.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                 url: url,
                 data: formData,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                 success: function (response) {
                     alert('succes!!');
                 },
                 error: function (error) {
                     alert("errror");
                 }
             });
```